# Are react JS attributes different from properties?

Tags: reactjs, syntax

I'm reading the react JS documentation and came across this:

**Specifying Attributes with JSX**:

`You may use quotes to specify string literals as attributes:
const element = <div tabIndex="0"></div>;`

I'm fairly comfortable with javascript but I'm not quite sure what the documentation means by "attributes". I know about object properties but this looks like a simple variable.

What exactly is a react js attribute if it is different from a property?

Comment: The react attributes are the same concept as plain HTML attributes, things you can assign to an element when defining the tag. And when it comes to HTML I'm pretty sure "attributes" and "properties" refer to the same thing

Answer (score 2):

html elements have both attributes and properties

there are a few different scenarios for how they relate to each other. There doesn't necessarily have to be both an attribute or property for each value set on an element.

**1. attributes**

attributes can be set in html

```
<a id="mylink" href=""/>
```

where *href* is an attribute

or attributes can be set by using the set attribute method of an element

```
document.getElementById("mylink").setAttribute("href", "")
```

and read using

```
document.getElementById("mylink").getAttribute("href")
```

**2. properties**

properties can be set and read by retrieving the element as well

```
document.getElementById("mylink").href = ""
```

where *href* is a property

when they are set the first way, you are setting the attribute, the second sets the property.

- Usually the underlying element attribute and property are
  automatically synchronized, sometimes they are not.
- Sometimes there is no matching attribute or property,
  only one or the other exists.

**Attributes and properties are part of native html elements, which *React* provides additional support and abstractions around.**

Custom React components (such as `<MyComponent prop=""/>` or `<MyComponent prop={someVar}/>`), which you create yourself, accept props using the same syntax. The word props in this context refers purely to React props. React custom component props are just plain javascript values passed into your component. These custom components don't get added to the page. They are used to organize and render actual html elements.

When mounting a native component inside of a custom component (such as `<div id=""/>` or `<div id={someVar}/>`), the React library sets the underlying html attribute on the native browser element.

So there are two things to keep in mind here

1. html element attributes verse html element properties.
2. custom element props are neither of those, but setting a prop on a JSX
   native element such as a *div*, set's the generated element's
   attribute.

Now that's been established, the documentation above is saying: if you want to set an attribute value to a string you can use that specific syntax. That syntax only works for setting attribute values to strings.

You can use either:

```
<div id="myid"/>
```

or

```
<div id={'myid'} />
```

to set a string attribute value. **They're probably just pointing out the syntax differences.**

if you do:

```
<div tabIndex="0"/>
```

the value of tabIndex is the string `0` not the number zero

verses this:

```
<div tabIndex={0} />
```

which will pass the number zero to the tabindex attribute of the underlying html element

Answer (score 0):

To me if we pass any parameter in **function component** then what we diclare in html is **properties**.But if you use **(className/style/etc...)** directecly in html then it will be **attributes**.